# How to remove a folder from a MonoTouch project?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop I can right click a file in a MonoTouch project and select "Remove" and it then gives me an option of removing the file from the project. However, if I right click a folder, the only option available is "Delete" which brings up a confirmation box saying that the entire folder will be deleted. How do I remove a folder from a MonoTouch project? Does this functionality exist somewhere or has it not been built yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to handle all the files outside of monodevelop.  Just move it to wherever you like and then delete the folder from inside monodevelop.

Comment: Yep, that works. I notice tho that you must delete all subfolders individually, you cannot just delete the root folder and have MonoDevelop delete the entire folder including subfolders. Thanks, Kiran.